# Excel Macro - Run-time error '5' when running in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel macro is written in Excel 2013, but when my colleague runs it in Excel 2010 he gets the following error:

> Run-time error '5'

I'm not really an expert in VBA. Why am I getting this error?

When I run the debugger, it points me to section below:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Tempo!R1C1:R5000C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Tempo2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Comment: DefaultVersion could prob be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

`xlPivotTableVersion15` is specific to Excel 2013.

Here are the possible values for that enumeration:

```
Value                     Version
-----------------------   ----------
xlPivotTableVersion2000   Excel 2000
xlPivotTableVersion10     Excel 2002
xlPivotTableVersion11     Excel 2003
xlPivotTableVersion12     Excel 2007
xlPivotTableVersion14     Excel 2010
xlPivotTableVersion15     Excel 2013
```

Try changing your macro to use `xlPivotTableVersion14` instead.

Comment: Hi Bond, thanks for helping. I changed it but still get the same Run-time error '5' and it point to below again :(     ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Tempo!R1C1:R5000C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Tempo2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14

Comment: You need to change it in both places: `Version` and `DefaultVersion`.